# POSIX Thread Running Time And Attribute Display In C

Tags: c, multithreading, time, pthreads, attr

I am working on a project for University which requires me to use POSIX threads in C. I have done most of the work but I have two major problems I can't seem to work out.

- First, I need to calculate the time a thread has been running. I can't figure which methods or functions I need to use for it.
- Second I have to display the attributes of each thread (created with `pthread_attr_init()`) as a message on the screen.

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide information as to what you are confused with, specifically? Figuring out a time delta is simple, so I'm sure there's something other than subtraction that is throwing you off.

Comment: I am confused towards which functions I should use to do it.  I am not very familiar with C as a programming language and I haven't found a satisfactory answer yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I measure time per thread in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718464/how-do-i-measure-time-per-thread-in-c)

Comment: You should ask one question at a time. Your first question is a duplicate of the one I've just linked to.

Comment: I was searching for it but I did not find such a question, I was searching with wrong search terms apparently. Thank a lot anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first you can use `getrusage()` with the "this thread only" option.

For the second, use `printf()` to print the fields of your pthread attribute struct.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the pthread attribute printing;